# X tickers problem with plotting against time in matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, linegraph

I am trying to write a define function to plot a line graph by the data of a imported a csv file.

This a small sample of my data( temperature reading for every minutes):-

```
00:01:00.0305040, 35.35985
00:02:00.0438094, 35.48547
00:03:00.0571148, 35.65295
00:04:00.0704203, 35.90417
00:05:00.0837257, 36.23914
.
.
.
.
08:52:07.2370729, 74.92772
08:53:07.2503783, 75.01146
08:54:07.2648837, 75.05333
08:55:07.2781891, 75.0952
08:56:07.2914945, 75.0952
```

When I try to set the x ticker to be appear every hour, they do not show up in the plotted graph.

This is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,names=["time", "temp"])
df["time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df=df.set_index('time')
df.index = df.index.map (lambda t: t.strftime('%H:%M'))
print(df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4, x_compat=True)
ax.set(xlabel='Time (Hour:Minutes)', ylabel='Temperature (Celsius)')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
return plt.show()
```

I have tried labeling the x tickers manually

```
plt.xticks(['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00:0', '5:00', '6:00:0', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00'])
```

and it worked, but it there a way for any given case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation

> All of plotting functions expect np.array or np.ma.masked_array as input. Classes that are 'array-like' such as pandas data objects and np.matrix may or may not work as intended. It is best to convert these to np.array objects prior to plotting.

So I changed your code slightly (basically converted the pd df into numpy array).

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file,names=["time", "temp"])
df["time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
x_axis = np.array(df.time.values)
y_axis = np.array(df.temp.values)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
ax.set(xlabel='Time (Hour:Minutes)', ylabel='Temperature (Celsius)')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.show()
```

The ticks are visible now as below.

[image]